# React Native build failed - Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: react-native, gradle

[when I run the app "npm react-native run-android" I face up this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYz82.png)

Comment: Have you enabled developer mode on your device ?

Comment: try just `react-native run-android` and `npm start`

Comment: I'm trying to run app on emulator...

Comment: React-native isnt recognized when i run "react-native run-android"